# wpa_supplicant is floading journal

Tags: systemd, wpa-supplicant

I have access to an guest connection to my neighbor Wlan. The Signal is week and sometimes I loose my internet connection. This i accept.
but wpa_supplicant fills my journal with

```
wpa_supplicant[983]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-78 noise=9999 txrate=1000
```

I took a look in the manpage, and found option -q (be quiet)
then I wrote an override by

```
systemctl edit wpa_supplicant.service
```

And changed Exec to

```
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -q -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

but after reload the systemd rules and restart from the service, I get

```
 wpa_supplicant.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

Great. 
How can I achive my goal? Do I really have to manipulate the origin file?

First thank's.
Then I get

```
 sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-29 15:43:26 CEST; 10s ago
 Main PID: 5023 (wpa_supplicant)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
           └─5023 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -q -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

Sep 29 15:43:26 beelzemon systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Sep 29 15:43:26 beelzemon systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Sep 29 15:43:26 beelzemon wpa_supplicant[5023]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Sep 29 15:43:26 beelzemon wpa_supplicant[5023]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
```

I will show if is something, to concern.

Comment: There is [this trick](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/14539): include an empty directive `ExecStart= ` right before the current ExecStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemd` does not allow you to modify the ExecStart line. It does, however, allow you to "reset" the ExecStart parameter using an empty directive:

```
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -q -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

See e.g. [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/14539). The ExecStart is actually an array in memory; the first directive empties the array.